# Navigating to fragment on backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 screens . 1->Fragment(inside fragmentactivity) 2->Fragment 3-> Activity. In screen 3 I call screen 1 to do something and I return again to screen 3. Now if I press back button in screen 3 I want to go to screen 2 instead of screen 1 . I tried this logic but it returned back to screen 1 instead of 2 .Any suggestions please?

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        Log.d("TAG","back button ");
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: when you want go from 1 -> 3 call `finish()`  method on fragment 1

Comment: I think it's better to handle back press with **onBackPressed** callback.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan your ans works but now when I press back in 3 . it loads 3 again and then I press back again,it goes to screen 2. I have removed the above piece of code from 3.

Comment: when you try call fragment 3 form 2 did you go as following? 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 3 ? if yes you need call finish method too when you call 1 from 3 ( 3 -> 1). so you need finish in 2 phase. 1. 1-> 3  2. 3 -> 1

Comment: Your solution worked . Thanks a lot. You can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want remove activity form Activity Stack you need call `finish()` method or start activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, as second solution remove all activity from Stack you don't need that.

in your situation you need call `finish()` method on following step:

1. 1-> 3
2. 3-> 1

Answer (score 0):

use addtobackstack in your fragment transaction:

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                           // Add this transaction to the back stack
                           .addToBackStack()
                           .commit();

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html